# Why is my display of none for my div in css being applied to all of its descendants even though I am setting one of the descendants to display block?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a page of mine.
The aim is that when I click on the image of apples, everything except for the rest of my images gets set to a display of none.

Here is my code:

```js
// hideAll() hides everything except the images in the fruits class.
function hideAll() {
  let fruit = document.querySelectorAll("div.main div.fruits");
  let mainContainer = document.querySelectorAll("div.main");
  mainContainer[0].style.display = 'none';
  for (i = 0; i < fruit.length; i++) {
    fruit[i].style.display = 'block';
    //fruit[i].style.setProperty('display', 'block', '!important'); //This did not work
  }
}
```

```css
.fruits {
  display: none;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.Categories {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Main Page</h1>
    <div class="base">
      <h2>Fruit Categories</h2>
      <div class="some-content">
        <p>This page contains some fruit information.</p>
        <div class="Categories">
          <p>We have apples, bananas, oranges, etc.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img src="https://foodprint.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/IMG_3392-e1539129880189.jpg" onclick="hideAll();">
      <div class="element-container">
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://foodprint.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/IMG_3392-e1539129880189.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://foodprint.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/imageedit_127_5581342771.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://i0.wp.com/moodymoons.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/img_8986.jpg?fit=4560%2C3000&ssl=1">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://www.naturalhealth365.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/blueberries.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.gBifOTB-F-wBTx3bzYPiGgHaE-?pid=ImgDet&rs=1">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.3yrzbKoKIgyR7eBhHma26AHaGm?pid=ImgDet&rs=1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Basically, all of the images contained within the div class of fruits (6 images in total) needs to get set to a display of "block". Everything else gets set to a display of none (when the apple image is clicked).

Since there are many divs (and nested divs) within the main class, I thought that I could set the entire main class to a display of none. Then, I could set all of the elements within the fruits class to a display of block. I even tried using the !important keyword within the fruits class to override the effect of setting everything within the main div to none but that did not seem to do the trick.

Is there any way of targeting css for every descendant of a div except for the one specified?

Comment: By hiding the container, you're hiding all of its contents. You need to hide the individual elements that you intend to hide.

Comment: Tip: if you call `querySelectorAll()` but then only do something with `[0]` you can just use `querySelector()`.

Comment: @Marc, I know, the thing is that there are many elements nested within the main class. Setting their display individually would be kinda tedious. Is there any way I could specify that the fruits class doesn't get hidden (or some sort of override)?

Comment: So use different classes to target. You say *"when I click on the image of apples, everything except for the rest of my images gets set to a display of none"*, but you don't have `class="fruits apple"` or `class="fruits orange"` (or example). If you click an `apple`, hide the `orange` classes, or vice versa (can be applied to others too, like `pear`, `grape`, etc.)

Comment: Or, building on Tim's comment, if you click `apple`, hide `.fruit:not(.apple)`, etc.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click the apples?  Everything except the apples is already hidden in your snippet, so you won't be able to click anything other than apples, and if the apples get hidden, you have nothing left to click.

Comment: Do you have a plan for how  users would revert back to showing all fruits after hiding all but one? This is rather important in deciding how to implement hiding and un-hiding fruits in both directrions.

Answer (score 0):

All of the children elements are not visible because their parent is invisible; not because they are inheriting anything, but because the element they are contained in is invisible.

The !important value only applies when you want to disrupt the CSS hierarchy; it has nothing to do with the HTML hierarchy.

In your case, you want to set the display attribute in your loop for each child individually; forget about the parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this snippet.

Note that I replaced your image `src` with placeholders since yours weren't showing up for me (and/or might stop showing up at some point).

It's coded such that all images show at the outset, and each time you click one, it'll hide itself and show all others. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but this behavior should at least illustrate how you can set it up for your needs.

```js
//capture all fruits into an array variable
let allFruits = [...document.querySelectorAll("#elcon > div.fruits")];

allFruits.forEach((fruit) => {
  //add a click listener on each fruit element
  fruit.addEventListener("click", () => {
    //show all fruits
    allFruits.forEach(e => e.style.display = 'block');
    //hide the fruit that got clicked
    fruit.style.display = 'none';
  })
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.Categories {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <h1>Main Page</h1>
    <div class="base">
      <h2>Fruit Categories</h2>
      <div class="some-content">
        <p>This page contains some fruit information.</p>
        <div class="Categories">
          <p>We have apples, bananas, oranges, etc.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="element-container" id="elcon">
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/000000">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF8000">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/8F0000">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/008000">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FF00">
        </div>
        <div class="fruits">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```